# Delete caseFeed when email message is deleted

Tags: emailmessage, casefeed

I would like to Delete casefeed whenever a email message is deleted. Current if I delete email message the mail record is getting deleted but still the case feed displaying in casefeed. (I Dont want to delete all the feeds Only perticular feeds need to be deleted.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is i deleted email message from trigger instead of this I called future method to delete emailmessage so feed also getting deleted

Answer (score 1):

You could query FeedItem record based on Parent Id and delete that

```
delete ([SELECT Id FROM FeedItem
WHERE ParentId =: <your email record Id>]);
```

Comment: It will delete all case feeds right?

Comment: yes, that should be

Comment: But i need to delete only the deleted email feed?

Comment: update my answer

Comment: ParentId Refered to case and not with email does it really work? strange..!

Comment: I tryed with email record id it is not working